# Replace element value in XML php

Tags: php, mxml

Hey I am looking for a way to replace an element value with another. What I have in mind is when a variable is equal to "Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood", this value is replaced by a new one. My project is developed with simplexml ( add, delete) but DOM is appreciated too. Thank you for your help!

My XML is

```
<Game type="adventure">
<TITLE>Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood</TITLE>
<PUBLISHER>Ubisoft</PUBLISHER>
</Game>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace string with var in PHP - XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632548/replace-string-with-var-in-php-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SimpleXML:

```
$games = simplexml_load_file('games.xml');
foreach ($games as $game) {
    if ($game->TITLE == "Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood") {
        $game->TITLE = "Kiss Me Kate";
    }
}
$games->asXML('games2.xml');
```